# Do SQLite database files get stored in memory in Flutter?

Tags: sqlite, flutter, dart, dart-pub

If I have a 10MBs SQLite database file that I'll open using the Sqflite package will those 10MBs get stored in the device RAM or the package will load data only as needed?!

Comment: It will be stored in cache folder.